# How to get a unique list in neo4j cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

For example, I have a list `[1,1,2]`,

What I expect result is `[1,2]`.

### what I tried

```
return [distinct x in [1,1,2]]
```

`Distinct` does not work , this will throw an error.

### something might help

is there any [list function](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/list/) I can use in neo4j to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the APOC library's `apoc.coll.toSet([list])` function.

These functions are documented [here](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/3.5/utilities/collection-list-functions/). The same manual includes details on how to install the APOC plugin.

**EDIT: Without APOC**

Here's one way to return a `set` from a `list` in CYPHER - unwind the list and then collect only the distinct values from it:

```
unwind [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5] as nums
with distinct nums return collect(nums);
```

or

```
unwind [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5] as nums
return collect(distinct nums);
```

Comment: thanks Jasper, I have not touched APOC. I believe it will work as expected. the current problem is that we are using neo4j in our production, I do no think that we install `APOC` on our production db.

Comment: If you prefer not to use APOC in prod, I've updated with a pure CYPHER way. A bit convoluted. Someone might provide a better approach.

Answer (score 3):

The `COLLECT` aggregating function supports the `DISTINCT` option:

```
UNWIND [1,1,2] AS list
RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT list);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something with REDUCE?

`REDUCE(distinctElements = [], element IN YOUR_ARRAY | CASE WHEN NOT element in distinctElements THEN distinctElements + element ELSE distinctElements END)`

Comment: Thanks nice option.

I used `apoc.coll.toSet()` solved my problem (from Jasper), but thanks for the answer as well.